# Return row number from Cells.Find method on another workbook

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I keep getting run-time error 91: Object variable or with block variable not set.

I need to return the row number of a string I'm searching for in another workbook and place it 6 columns away from the name I'm looking up. The names have slight variations in the strings which is why I preferred using `Cells.Find` as opposed to vlookup.

I tried setting the range I'm searching in as a public range to no avail. Both workbooks are open but it seems as if the `Cells.Find` method only works when the workbook with the range I'm searching in is active.

FYI, `listrange` is the range of names on the active workbook. `clientlist` is a named range in the other workbook I'm searching in (open but not active), `clientlist2` is the declared version of that named range.

Here's the code snippet:

```
Public clientlist2 As Range

Sub sortout()

    Dim wkb As Workbook
    Dim clientwks As Worksheet
    Dim listrange As Range

    Set wkb = Workbooks("workbook.xlsm")
    Set clientwks = wkb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set clientlist2 = clientwks.Range("clientlist")
    Set listrange = Range("A6", Range("A6").End(xlDown))

    For Each a In listrange

        a.Offset(0, 6).value = clientlist2.Cells.Find(a).Row

    Next a

End Sub
```

Comment: `Set listrange = Range("A6", Range("A6").End(xlDown))` What sheet should that be from? You clarified for `clientwks` and `clientlist2`, but not this one.  Make sure to put the worksheet before both uses of `Range()`  Also, what line throws your error?

Comment: listrange opens on sheet1 of a temporary workbook that is generated from another program. The error is thrown in the For loop at this line: a.Offset(0, 6).value = clientlist2.Cells.Find(a).Row
I'll try it now, thanks for the speedy reply!

Comment: Thanks Bruce, but I'm still getting the error at the same line.

Comment: Oh, I think it's because you're trying to set a cell value to a row's value. `clientlist2.cells.find(a).Row` should be  ...what? Do you want to return the `.Row`? What are you trying to set the `.Value` to?

Comment: @BruceWayne  I'm pretty sure [range.row](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196952.aspx) returns a integer-value?

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise you to do the operation inside the for-statement in two steps to avoid errors, and to make it easier to troubleshoot.

If I was going to find a cell, and then copy something (or some property) from it, I'd first attempt to set it to a variable, and then check what result I got from that before attempting to  do anything more with it.

In your case;

```
Dim foundValue As Range
For Each a In listrange
  Set foundValue = clientlist2.Cells.Find(a)
  If Not foundValue Is Nothing Then
    a.Offset(0, 6).Value = foundValue.Row
  End If
Next a
```

This also makes it easier to troubleshoot, as you can examine what values your different variables have at each step of the way, by using e.g. `Debug.Print` or message boxes.

Another good idea is adding `Option Explicit` at the top of your module. This makes it necessary for you to define (dim) all your variables, preventing accidental misspellings in the middle of your code.

Comment: Thanks eirik, that helped in stopping the error but it only worked on one name that's an exact match. The other names have characters not found in the clientlist2 strings. I tried using "*" & a & "*" to work around it but it's not working.

Comment: Does it help providing more arguments to [`Find`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)? E.g. setting `Lookat:=xlPart`? It's a bit hard knowing what is causing the find to fail, without knowing more about what strings you put into the function. Maybe you could add a couple of examples to your question? @user6100466

Comment: I managed to add formatting rules that make it easier for the find to work. Here's an example of one that does not work: "Something Finance LTD" and in the other workbook it's just listed as "Something". There are many names like this that aren't pulling any data.

Comment: @user6100466 You are searching for the string something ltd and want to find something, or vice versa?

Comment: I have "Something Finance LTD" on one sheet, and I'm trying to match it with the name "Something" in the other workbook and return the row number.

Comment: Yes, but which are you using for which input to the find-function? @user6100466

Answer (score -2):

I you think the problem occur when the workbook is deactive, so activate it before find method.

Workbooks("BOOK4.XLS").Activate